# Find the pdf of $\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i$, where N follows geometric distribution and $X_i$ follows $exp(\lambda)$

Tags: probability

Suppose $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ are i.i.d. exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$. Let N be geometric random variable with parameter $p$. N is independent of {$X_i$}. Find the pdf of $\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i$.

As far as I know, the sum of n i.i.d. exponential random variables with common parameter $\lambda$ follows Gamma$(n,\lambda)$. But how do I apply geometric distribution to the subscript?
Say $P(N=k)=(1-p)^{k-1}p$. Let $Z=\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i$. Is the general case $P(Z\lt z)=P(\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_i\lt z)\times P(N=k)$? or should I use the law of total probability $P(Z\lt z)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i\lt z|N=k)\times P(N=k)$

Comment: You take what you wrote there at the end and sum it over $k$. (That said, there is a clever way to use the concept of a Poisson process to answer this question more easily.)

Comment: @Ian you mean I shall use the law of total probability?

Comment: Yes, but in this particular way (marginalizing over $N$).

Comment: @Ian I've edited my post. But I have trouble calculating this result. Can you help me with that?

Comment: You should try with Moment-generating function, find $M_{\sum_{i=1}^N x_i}(t)=E(e^{t\sum x_i})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(e^{t\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}|N=n)P(N=n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_x(t)^n P(N=n)$, which is actually $=P_N(M_x(t))$, where $P_N(.)$ is the Probability-generating function of geometric distribution